# Why is an installation is required for ClickOnce .NET deployment

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce, bootstrapping

I am probably being a bit naive, but need to quickly create some low footprint apps (using Telerik Components) to a number of customers.  This is a quick and dirty solution to overcome lack of Oracle software on different laptop builds.

I had an idea that ClickOnce would allow me to package the application up with all dependencies, and there would be no software installation required.  I work in a large corporate environment, software installation requires admin access. So hosting a self contained application with all dependencies (ClickOnce) sounded great, simply host the app on a global file share.

Working through the reality of it, the application isn't self contained. It requires a bootstrap application and creation of a setup.exe. My customers can't install software (no admin access), nor would I want to install software dependencies which may be outside the corporate standard (.NET version).

I am assuming when people have to install the pre-requisites via setup.exe, I could end up overwriting the installed .NET version on the client, or my customers may not be able to execute setup.exe as they do not have admin rights to install software.

Any advice appreciated, perhaps I am misunderstanding the process. I was hoping for a fully self contained application people could open, have dependencies available to that running application, no installation required, and zero footprint change to corporate client.

Answer (score 1):

ClickOne isn't magic. Strip everything away and it's very basic. It copies files into your user profile and keeps those in sync with files on a server. That's it. Yes, it can do extra stuff like add an entry in "Add/Remove Programs", create start menu shortcuts, etc., but at its heart it just syncs files between a client and a server.

There's "extra" stuff (like the bootstrapper aka setup.exe) that tries to solve other problems but that's really outside the realm of ClickOnce. The bootstrapper tries to make installing dependencies easier. Without the bootstrapper you'd tell a user to first install .NET, then go find the Oracle bits and install those, then go launch the ClickOnce app. Instead, you wrap all those up into a single install. It will check if .NET is installed, skip it if it's there, move on to Oracle, then finally launch your ClickOnce app at the end.

It's confusing because Visual Studio lumps it all together and makes it look like the bootstrapper is part of ClickOnce. It isn't. There's no magic way to install a prerequisite other than simply installing it. And if that prerequisite requires admin access to install, there's no way around it, an admin has to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps you, but from ClickOnce Wikipedia page:
*ClickOnce-deployed applications are considered "low impact", in that they are installed per-user, not per-machine. No administrator privileges are required to install one of these applications. Each ClickOnce application is isolated from the others. This means one ClickOnce application is not able to "break" another*

Comment: Hi,  but then there could be a setup.exe created which needs to install an entire .net framework if prerequisite target is not met?  Is that a local .net installation -  seems crazy that a .net 4.5 installation can be done as low impact and without admin access?